# DevExtreme refresh grid

Tags: refresh, devextreme, dx-data-grid

```
form: {
            labelLocation: "left",
            items: [
                {
                    dataField: "PART_CODE",
                    dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                    visible: true,//Default Value: true
                    isRequired: true,//Default Value: undefined

                    editorType: "dxTextBox",//Accepted Values: 'dxAutocomplete' | 'dxCalendar' | 'dxCheckBox' | 'dxColorBox' | 'dxDateBox' | 'dxDropDownBox' | 'dxLookup' | 'dxNumberBox' | 'dxRadioGroup' | 'dxRangeSlider' | 'dxSelectBox' | 'dxSlider' | 'dxSwitch' | 'dxTagBox' | 'dxTextArea' | 'dxTextBox'
                    editorOptions: {
                        showClearButton: true,//Default Value: false
                    },

                    validationRules: [
                        {type: "required"},
                        {type: "stringLength", max: 10},
                    ],
                },
                {},
                {
                    dataField: "PNAME_CODE",
                    dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                    visible: true,//Default Value: true
                    isRequired: true,//Default Value: undefined

                    editorType: "dxSelectBox",//Accepted Values: 'dxAutocomplete' | 'dxCalendar' | 'dxCheckBox' | 'dxColorBox' | 'dxDateBox' | 'dxDropDownBox' | 'dxLookup' | 'dxNumberBox' | 'dxRadioGroup' | 'dxRangeSlider' | 'dxSelectBox' | 'dxSlider' | 'dxSwitch' | 'dxTagBox' | 'dxTextArea' | 'dxTextBox'
                    editorOptions: {
                        showClearButton: true,//Default Value: false

                        onValueChanged: function (data) {
                            console.log(data.parent);
                            alert(data.value);

                        },
                    },

                    validationRules: [
                        {type: "required"},
                    ],
                },
                {
                    dataField: "PART_NAME",
                    dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                    visible: true,//Default Value: true
                    isRequired: true,//Default Value: undefined

                    editorType: "dxTextBox",//Accepted Values: 'dxAutocomplete' | 'dxCalendar' | 'dxCheckBox' | 'dxColorBox' | 'dxDateBox' | 'dxDropDownBox' | 'dxLookup' | 'dxNumberBox' | 'dxRadioGroup' | 'dxRangeSlider' | 'dxSelectBox' | 'dxSlider' | 'dxSwitch' | 'dxTagBox' | 'dxTextArea' | 'dxTextBox'
                    editorOptions: {
                        showClearButton: true,//Default Value: false
                    },

                    validationRules: [
                        {type: "required"},
                        {type: "stringLength", max: 50},
                    ],
                },
                {
                    dataField: "PART_BIGO",
                    dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                    visible: true,//Default Value: true
                    isRequired: false,//Default Value: undefined

                    editorType: "dxTextArea",//Accepted Values: 'dxAutocomplete' | 'dxCalendar' | 'dxCheckBox' | 'dxColorBox' | 'dxDateBox' | 'dxDropDownBox' | 'dxLookup' | 'dxNumberBox' | 'dxRadioGroup' | 'dxRangeSlider' | 'dxSelectBox' | 'dxSlider' | 'dxSwitch' | 'dxTagBox' | 'dxTextArea' | 'dxTextBox'
                    editorOptions: {
                        showClearButton: true,//Default Value: false
                        height: 80,
                    },

                    validationRules: [
                        {type: "stringLength", max: 500},
                    ],
                },
                {},
                {
                    id: "testGrid",
                    editorType: "dxDataGrid",
                    editorOptions: {
                        height : "390px",
                        dataSource: test,
                        columns: [
                        {
                            caption: "파트코드",
                            dataField: "PART_CODE",
                            dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                            visible: true,//Default Value: true
                        },
                        {
                            caption: "품명",
                            dataField: "PROD_NAME",
                            // dataField: "PNAME_NAME",
                            dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                            visible: true,//Default Value: true
                        },
                        {
                            caption: "파트명",
                            dataField: "PART_NAME",
                            dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                            visible: true,//Default Value: true
                        },
                        {
                            caption: "비고",
                            dataField: "PART_BIGO",
                            dataType: "string",//Accepted Values: undefined (Default) | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'boolean' | 'object' | 'datetime'

                            visible: true,//Default Value: true
                        },
                    ],

                    sorting: {
                        mode: "multiple"
                    },
                    allowColumnReordering: true,
                    allowColumnResizing: true,
                    columnAutoWidth: true,
                    groupPanel: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    selection: {
                        mode: "single"
                    }
                    },

                },

            ],

        },
```

When I change dxSelectBox selection, refresh the 'editorType: dxDataGrid'

The dxDataGrid dataSource must change on dxSelectBox. so I try it

The test was CustomStore, it works.

I want use other declared popup, but I can't use that use editing

If impossible to refresh, I want find other way..

Is it possible to refresh in test ajax success function?

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I reload my .NET MVC datagrid using JQuery.

You can use any event but I call it using this one:

```
.OnRowUpdated("reloadMainDataGrid")
```

With this function in JQuery:

```
function reloadMainDataGrid() {
    $("#MainDataGrid").dxDataGrid("getDataSource").reload();
}
```

I hope that helps guide you to the right answer if nothing else.